# Not able to connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi I am new to mongodb I tried connecting to mongodb://localhost:27017 but its not printing any  console and also not throwing any error

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
```

```
if (err) throw err

console.log('Connected');
})
```

Comment: you should put the the database name after the connection string
`MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname', (err, db) => {if (err) throw err; console.log('Connected');`

Comment: I tried with adding database name still not working

Comment: In your code you don't connect to any database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/:27017/animals', (err, client) => {
  if (err) throw err
    console.log('Connected')
})
    ---    
This is the whole code its not printing any console also not throwing error
how can I check that I am connected to mongodb and its running properly